# Image flicker in recyclerview with glide

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I am using glide 3.7 to load images in recyclerview from firebase storage. When new image is added to recyclerview and notifiydatasetchanged is called then all the existing images in recyclerview flickers and reloads again. How can I avoid image flickering when notifydatasetchanged is called. 
here is my adapter class

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "RecyclerAdapter";


    private Context mContext;
    private List<ModelGridItems> gridItemsList;
    private boolean fromService;

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<ModelGridItems> list, boolean fromservice) {
        gridItemsList = list;
        mContext = context;
        fromService = fromservice;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.grid_items, parent, false);
        return new RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        try {
            holder.bind(gridItemsList.get(position));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (gridItemsList == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return gridItemsList.size();
    }





    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView btnAction;
        TextView tvParticipantName;
        ImageView ivParticipantImage;
        TextView tvConnection;

        MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ivParticipantImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            btnAction = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_more);

            tvParticipantName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_username);
            tvParticipantName.setTypeface(BaseActivity.typefaceCabinBold);

            tvConnection = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
            tvConnection.setTypeface(BaseActivity.typefaceCabinBold);

        }

        void bind(final ModelGridItems item) {
            tvParticipantName.setText(item.getParticipantName());
            if (item.getIsConnecting()) {
                tvConnection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                tvConnection.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (item.getParticipantId().equals(BaseActivity.mUniqueId)) {
                btnAction.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            if (BaseActivity.mUniqueId.equals(item.getParticipantId())) {
                loadProfileImage();

            } else {
                StorageReference storageReference = BaseActivity.storageReference.child(AppConfig.profileBucket + item.getParticipantId() + AppConfig.ImageExtension);
                SharedMethods.loadFromCloudCircular(mContext, ivParticipantImage, storageReference);
            }
            btnAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    showAnchorMenu(btnAction, item.getParticipantId());
                }

            });
            ivParticipantImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (fromService) {
                        Intent groupCallIntent = new Intent(mContext, GroupCall.class);
                        groupCallIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        groupCallIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("GridItems", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) gridItemsList);
                        mContext.startActivity(groupCallIntent);
                    } else {
                        SharedMethods.showLargeImageFromCloud(mContext, item.getParticipantId());
                    }

                }
            });


        }

        private void loadProfileImage() {
            if (SharedMethods.isPermissionGranted(SharedMethods.PERMISSION_WRITE_STORAGE, mContext)) {
                SharedMethods.loadFromLocalStorageCircular((Activity) mContext, ivParticipantImage, SharedMethods.profileImagePath());
            } else {
                StorageReference storageReference = BaseActivity.storageReference.child(AppConfig.profileBucket + BaseActivity.mUniqueId + AppConfig.ImageExtension);
                SharedMethods.loadFromCloudCircular(mContext, ivParticipantImage, storageReference);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

THis method lads images from firebase storage

```
public static void loadFromCloudCircular(final Context context, final ImageView imageView, StorageReference storageReference) {
        Glide.with(context)
                .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                .load(storageReference)
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.unknown_image)
                .transform(new CircularTransform(context))
                .into(new SimpleTarget<GlideDrawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, GlideAnimation<? super GlideDrawable> glideAnimation) {
                        imageView.setImageDrawable(resource);
                        Dashboard.isCircularLoaded = true;
                    }
                });


    }
```

I tried different options like setHasStableIds(true) but this adds the item to top of existing items and the animates to its position. Also tried with itemanimator shown below, but image always flicker. Any help?

```
ItemAnimator animator = rv.getItemAnimator();
if (animator instanceof SimpleItemAnimator) {
    ((SimpleItemAnimator) animator).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Suggestion 1: Use Picasso instead of Glide
>   [Picasso Square Image Viewer](https://github.com/square/picasso)

I somehow don't like Glide, and Picasso is similar to it in syntax.

> Suggestion 2: Don't use images that are above 1MB

It is memory intensive and has no effect on the image quality if you view it in 250dp height of you mobile. Better to reduce the size of the image and send it to firebase, if you are uploading from the app itself. **If you need help with that reduction in size of Image** check this link.[Codota link to compress images to required size](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/android.graphics.Bitmap/compress)

> **Important Suggestion: Don't use the animation for now and check if it still flickers**

Try these suggestions and check if it helps.